# jQuery preloading images from PHP to prevent flicker

Tags: php, jquery, image, preload

Page is refreshed every 5 seconds. Images that received from `.php` file are appended to some `<li >` elements.

Here is the code:

```
function reloadImages(){
   for ( i = 0; i < ImgNum; i++) {
      var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
      $('li#' + i).html('<img src="img.php?session=<?php echo $session; ?>&img=' + i + '&time='+ ts +'  " />')
   }
}
```

Everything works as expected. But when `reloadImages()` is called, Images are flickering during the reload.

How to prevent this flicker? Preload Images?

Help me address the flickering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the folowing mechanism of preload and callback (is'n tested actually)

```
function reloadImages(){
 for ( i = 0; i < ImgNum; i++) {
  var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
     //this is old image        
     $('li#' + i).find('img').addClass('oldimage');   
     //adding and loading new image
     $('<img style="display:none;"/>').appendTo($('li#' + i))
                  .attr("src", "img.php?session=<?php echo $session; ?>&img=' + i + '&time='+ ts +'  ")
                  .load(function(){
                  //when it is loaded hide the old one
                   $(this).show();
                   $(this).parent().find('.oldimage').hide().remove();        
      })
 }
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded plugin to load images into `display: none;` div and then move them to your destionation on callback.

Comment: It's be lovely to see an example of this